# Run a pre job before GitLab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, devops, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml, gitlab-pipelines

I want to run a job each time a new pipeline gets triggered. It's a kind of preparation job which should always be executed before every other job defined inside the `.gitlab-ci.yml`

For Example

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

my-prep-job:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    # this is the job I want to run every time a pipeline gets triggered before other jobs
    # also it will have an artifact that I want to use in rest of the job
  ...
  artifacts:
    ...

Build:
  stage: build
  ...

Test:
  stage: test
  ....
```

Please, let me know if this is possible or if there is other way around.

Thanks in Advance...

**Edit**

I did try adding **.pre** under **stages**.
Thing is I had to rewrite the rules and add it to **my-prep-job** stages as well.

```
stages:
  - .pre # I did add it over here
  - build
  - test
```

Also I had to add the **rules** to this stage as well so that it would not run on it's own on just a normal commit/push.

Is there any possibility to extend ".pre" stage of GitLab pipeline?

Comment: You're setting a `.pre` stage on your job, but you also need to define that stage in your `stages` list before any other stages

Comment: I have. But it made me do add a lot of stuff. I was thinking if we could somehow extends the ".pre" stage of GitLab. Is that even possible/

Comment: `.pre` is an implied stage. You can use it for any job and it does not need to be defined explicitly in `stages:`. Also if pipeline rules reult in jobs _only_ in the `.pre` or `.post` stages, the pipeline will not run by defualt. See the [stages documention](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`!reference`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags) tags to include certain keyword sections.
For example:

```
.pre
  script:
    - echo from pre

example:
  stage: test
  script:
    - !reference [.pre, script]
    - ...
```

Will include the `script` part of `.pre` into the example job.

You can use `!reference` for most of the job keywords like `artifacts` or `rules`

Comment: But as you can see, when you reference it, you basically just adding script to the `example` stage. I am not sure the artifacts would work, as I have tried it. And for it to be available to other jobs, it first needs to be executed, right!!!.